# Tokenize a string with a specific multi-byte delimiter

Tags: c, string, token, strtok

I need to parse a string like this:

`link:a link:blink:c link:d lkjh`

The output should be `a`, `blink:c`, `d`

But the output using `strtok` understably is `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `jh`

How do I make sure only `link:` explicitly splits the string (avoiding the case of `blink:c` getting split.
Also how do I ensure the last `kjh` don't appear (k seems to be the delimiter here).

Comment: Seems to me that the input might need to be parsed as "link:b link:c" and not as "blink:c". Are you sure about your requirements?

Comment: Your requirements are unclear, at the very least. If you want, simply `link:` to split the string, then `link:b` an `link:c` would and should be two different tokens. On the other hand, if you want ` link:` (with a leading space) to split the string, then the first token would be `link:a` since it lacks the leading space. You should probably clarify what it is that you actually want.

Comment: @kaylum, I'm sure, it needs to output "blink:c"

Comment: @Dolda2000, I think I am clear about what I want. I want to produce a token starting with first "link:" until the next null/empty space

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, passing a delimiter string to `strtok` does not do what you seem to think.  If you pass `"link:"` as the `delim` field, it will use *any* of those characters as a delimiter.  This is why `lkjh` is being split and returning `jh`.

You are better off splitting by spaces, and then checking the beginning matches `"link:"`.

```
const char * delim = " ";
const char * prefix = "link:";
const size_t len_prefix = strlen( prefix );

char * token = strtok( input_string, delim );
while( token != NULL ) {
    if( 0 == strncmp( token, prefix, len_prefix )
    {
        printf( "%s\n", token + len_prefix );
    }
    token = strtok( NULL, delim );
}
```

If you need something more complicated than this, roll your own or use a regular expression.

Comment: Hi, why are you printing printf( "%s\n", token + len_prefix ); ? I don't understand the need for concatenating this. 
What I understand, is you have obtained space split tokens, and are now comparing for first 5 chars to be equal to link: and then trying to print the rest of it.. Is this right?

Comment: That's correct.  The remainder of the string following the prefix begins at `token + len_prefix`.  That's pointer arithmetic, not concatenation.  You can do what you want with it.  Copy it out somewhere or whatever.  In this case, I just print it to standard out.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

Basically find the first link: and then keep moving forward till the next space/null, and repeat on the string remnant.

Better approach is to simply use strstr:-

```
char* parseSubFn(char *string)
```

{

```
    if(string==NULL || *string=='\0')
    return;

    else{
    //printf("Parsing on %s \n",string);
    const char* needle = "link:";
    char ret[128];//large buffer character for return token
    char *location=strstr(string,needle);
    char *start=location+5;
    int i=0; 
    while(*start!='\0' && *start!='\n' && *start!=' ')
    {
    ret[i]=*start;
    start++;i++;
    }
    start++;
    printf("%s\n",ret);
    parseSubFn(start);
    }
```

}